# CakePHP Email encoding issue

Tags: php, email, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a form that once submitted sends an email to the person who entered the details. This form is for a Japanese website.

I need the encoding of the email to be in UTF-8 not swift-jis

I have added these 2 lines to my email controller:

```
$this->Email->charset = "utf-8";
$this->Email->headerCharset = "utf-8";
```

The text is email is appearing mostly ok, however I am still getting  � symbols with certain characters.

Anyone know what else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

first : change the defult-encoding in php.ini to utf-8 .
two : if you using ajax for sending email use "encodeURIComponent" for encode message .